# Is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ a fraction or not?

Tags: terminology

Is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ a fraction or not?

I just came across a Grade 8 student's class work where the teacher has given the above as an example to differentiate fractions from rational numbers. I think this is wrong fundamentally, as $\sqrt2$ is irrational while all fractions would be rational. Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: It would be good if you define what fraction means to you.

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(mathematics): 'the word fraction is also used to describe mathematical expressions that are not rational numbers, for example algebraic fractions (quotients of algebraic expressions)'

Comment: it is fraction but not a rational number,as you have mentioned

Comment: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$ is not a fraction since a fraction is a quotient of two numbers $$p,q$$ with $$p,q$$ are integer numbers

Comment: @Divesh M As you can see, it really depends on the definition of fraction you're using.

Comment: @Math_QED: yes but in a way, this is what the OP is asking.

Comment: In the narrow sense, a fraction is what you denote $\frac pq$ with $p,q$ integers, which evaluates to a rational. In a larger sense, $p,q$ can be arbitrary expressions.

Comment: People, people, let's all calm down.  None of this matters because differentiating any constant will result in zero.

Comment: There's no regulating body which has mandated a single definition of fraction. It's a question of usage. You may not know that there's a general theory of learned discourse. It holds that one should sound out the opinion of whomever one's talking to, then take the opposite opinion for more sophisticated or prestigious reasons. In this case one should cite the Oxford English Dictionary which just says a fraction is not a whole number.

Comment: $1/{\sqrt 2}$ is not a fraction over the ring of integers $\,\Bbb Z\,$ but it is a fraction over the ring $\,\Bbb Z[\sqrt 2],\,$ the numbers of form $\,j+k\sqrt 2\,$ for integers $j,k.\ \ $

Answer (score 19):

The word "fraction" is used outside of the scope of rational numbers as well. In that case, it's better not to use the term "fraction" to denote a *kind of number*, but rather to refer to the way of writing or representing it: i.e. as a structure with a **numerator** and a **denominator**.

Loosely speaking you could say *"$\pi$ is not a fraction"* because it cannot be written as a quotient of integers, but it's safer to say *"$\pi$ is not a rational number"* where you rely on a precise definition of *rational number*.

---

Generally, you want to be able to call anything of the form
$$\frac{a}{b}$$
a **fraction** because then you can refer to its two characterizing components: the numerator $a$ and the denominator $b$ with $a$ and $b$ not necessarily integers but any numbers or even more general expressions. Note that you can write any number $x$, not necessarily integer, as a fraction:
$$x = \frac{x}{1}$$but we generally don't refer to "$x$" as "a fraction". We do want to be able to call something like
$$\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{1-\sqrt{3}}$$a fraction, although it's not a rational number, because then we can say things such as *"multiply numerator and denominator with $1+\sqrt{3}$"*. The same goes for more complicated expressions (with fractions in fractions!), or even with one or more variables, such as:
$$\frac{e^2 - \frac{\sqrt{5}}{1+\sin\frac{\pi}{7}}}{1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}} \quad ; \quad \frac{e^x-\sin y}{x^2+y}$$

---

Summarizing:

> Is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ a fraction or not?

I think we prefer to be able to call this a fraction, with numerator $1$ and denominator $\sqrt{2}$, but then obviously we shouldn't mix "fraction" with "rational number" or use them interchangeably.

Comment: +1 This answer implicitly and correctly makes the point that there is no universally accepted meaning for the term - so both the student's teacher and the OP are wrong to insist on a "right definition".  .

Comment: @EthanBolker - While I agree with your point, don't be too quick to call the teacher wrong. We don't know the context of the teacher's comments, and the teacher has both the need and the right to determine the terminology that will be used in class and to explain the issues with other terminology

Comment: @PaulSinclair I agree - if the teacher has really talked about the definition, and understands that this is really a discussion about the definition = what we choose to call a particular mathematical object, not what the object is - i.e. its mathematical properties. Most teachers don't, though in my experience they're open to the idea when I point it out to them. I encountered this recently in a first grade class puzzling about the number of faces of a cone.

Answer (score 4):

I think 'fraction' is not really a well-defined mathematical term, but rather, is used to refer to a visual object which represents a number.

I would simply call anything which has a top and bottom a 'fraction', ie. anything in the form $\frac{???}{???}$.

This might include algebraic terms in it, in which case you wouldn't necessarily know if the object is rational or not. But I think most would agree that the object is a 'fraction'.

Whether something is a 'fraction' isn't a well defined property you can place on any number.

For example, you wouldn't call the object '$2\times 0.3$' a fraction, but you would for '$\frac{3}{5}$', although the two expressions are equal.

---

In the end, I think if the teacher said something along the lines of: a fraction is an object in the form $???\over???$ where the top is called 'the numerator', and the bottom, 'the denominator', then I believe the example shown demonstrates why not all fractions are rationals well enough.

Answer (score 3):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(mathematics)#Radical_expressions):

> A fraction may also contain radicals in the numerator and/or the denominator. If the denominator contains radicals, it can be helpful to rationalize it, especially if further operations, such as adding or comparing that fraction to another, are to be carried out...

In your case: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\times \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

Comment: Hence $\frac{4}{1}$ is a fraction but $4$ is not. Ok...

Comment: @leonbloy Where in there do I claim $\frac 41$ is a fraction? I'm purely talking about things with a square root (radical) in the denominator/numerator...

Comment: My point (poorly stated) is that we first need to agree on what a fraction is. Either it's a "kind of number" (as the accepted answer aptly notes) or it's just some notation. In the first case, it coincides with the rationals (and then $1/\sqrt{2}$ is not a fraction). If we opt for the latter, then $\frac41$ is a fraction.

Comment: @leonbloy I see where you're coming from now. I didn't consider that as I've always been taught that anything of the form $\dfrac{a}{b+\sqrt{c}}$ was a fraction, without really considering what that meant.

Answer (score -4):

"Fraction" just means "not a whole number."  For instance, irrational numbers can be written as "decimal fractions", like $\pi = 3.14159\ldots.$  If you had said "rational numbers" instead of "fractions", you'd be right.

Comment: Is $\frac{2}{1}$ not a fraction?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a fraction.  I'd call it rational.

Comment: Depends on the definition you use I guess.

Comment: I disagree with all your statements. The expression $\pi$ is certainly not a fraction. And integers are rational but I wouldn't call them fractions either.

Comment: @Shuri2060  Yes.  But the real problem is that "fraction" is not a well-defined math term, while "rational number" is.  (I'm a crossword fanatic and the roots of "fraction" jump out at me, perhaps, more than at others.  If you frac something, you break it.  Fracture, Fractious.  Fractal.  Fragment. )  Since it's not well-defined, the OP is not really answerable.

Comment: @YvesDaoust You don't disagree with "all" my statements, since you agree that integers aren't fractions.  But lots of people call any decimal expansion a "decimal fraction".

Comment: Fraction is a broad concept, and irrational numbers are included per wiki. So at least, this is not a wrong answer (+1)

Comment: Ok, let's be rigourous. I disagree with your first sentence and your third sentence, and your second sentence is irrelevant to the question. You confuse fraction and fractional number.

Comment: I disagree with "fraction" == "not a whole number" but I also was never really consciously aware of the ambiguity of the definition of fraction.  So I guess it doesn't matter.  And googling "fraction" results in two Google definitions at the top of the page, the first of which is "a numerical quantity that is not a whole number."  Then again, Google also thinks that a Hilbert space is "an infinite-dimensional analog of Euclidean space" no matter how many times I use that feedback feature.  [eye-roll]

Comment: @YvesDaoust  This should be good.  Please tell us what the difference is between the ill-defined "fraction" and the ill-defined "fractional number."  Since neither has rigorous definition, it's just plain silly for you to assert that someone might confuse the two terms.

Comment: A fraction is an algebraic expression with a numerator and a denominator. A fractional number is a real number (one might accept that *strictly fractional* numbers exclude the integers), regardless how it is written. The two concepts are clearly distant.

Comment: @YvesDaoust As predicted:  You have your own personal definitions and everyone has to bow to your will.  Pah.

Comment: Thanks StackTD...your answer is comprehensible and sensible!