# Formal definition of fraction

Tags: fractions

What is the **formal definition** of fraction?

Everyone says something different.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You have formal definition of rational numbers, not sure about fractions.

Comment: That's because there *is* no formal definition of fraction! It's a term that lots of different people use in lots of different (albeit very related) ways.

Comment: Related: [Is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ a fraction or not?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2348357/is-frac1-sqrt2-a-fraction-or-not).

Comment: "Everyone says something different". This raises the question of *what they say*, because either you are speaking to one of those people right now - in which case he will alwas say one of those different things you aren't satisfied with - or you are speaking to someone else who can't possibly know what they said to you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, in abstract algebra the concept of localization provides a formal definition of a fraction.  In short a fraction is an ordered pair $(a,b)$ (usually expressed $\frac{a}{b}$), along with the equivalence $(a,b) = (c,d)$ if $ad=bc$.

Comment: would you ignore $b$ without $b^{-1}$?